# Python: how to drop all the non numeric values from a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like the follwoing

```
    Rooms   BFS
0   3.5     4201
1   1.5     4201
2   NA      4201
3   NA      4201
4   5.5     4201
5   5       4201
6   4.5     4201
7   3       4201
8           4201
9   3       4201
```

I want to `drop` all the non numeric values from the column `Rooms`. All the values in `Rooms` are now considered as `str`

Comment: `df.Rooms=pd.to_numeric(df.Rooms,errors='coerce')` and dropna()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` and [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) for filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['Rooms'],errors='coerce').notna()]
print (df)
  Rooms   BFS
0   3.5  4201
1   1.5  4201
4   5.5  4201
5     5  4201
6   4.5  4201
7     3  4201
9     3  4201
```

If need numeric in output first assign to same column and then use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['Rooms'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rooms'],errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Rooms'])
print (df)
   Rooms   BFS
0    3.5  4201
1    1.5  4201
4    5.5  4201
5    5.0  4201
6    4.5  4201
7    3.0  4201
9    3.0  4201
```